# Mesh displacement and normal map artifacts in Eevee

Tags: geometry-nodes, shaders, normals

In my project, I'm using *Geometry Nodes* to displace a mesh and then, in a shader, adding additional texture via a combo of *Noise Texture*, various mapping nodes and then *Bump*.

I'm seeing all sorts of unusual artifacts in the material. I'm guessing it's because the tangents are not recalculated after the geometry displacement ... or perhaps it's using the original normals.

Here's a picture of what's going on and a (simplified) project file is attached as well.

[image: The weird normals]

[image: The shader]

Is there a way to make this look better?

TY!

[image]

(Blender 3.6+)

Comment: The main issue is the strength of the bump.  You are starting with a bump ranging from 0  to 5.0 (object space blender units, obj space *meters*; this combination of inputs and distance is appropriate maybe for asteroids in 1:1 scale, not for your 2m square); you are then interpolating the normal away from the base normal ten-fold with your strength.  This is probably interacting with some bugs, already reported, regarding the use of custom normals, but you're already way out of reasonable values for your bump.  (Bump does not depend on any kind of tangent, and it's not using pre-GN normals.)

Comment: Thank you @Nathan. I wasn't thinking that these were object space units, so it makes perfect sense that the values in my shader were outside of a reasonable range. In my mind, I'm picturing that I'm trying to display Pinocchio's nose on a surface using normal mapping.